# Ubuntu chrome remote desktop authentication super user

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, authentication, policykit

I tried to use google remote access to my Ubuntu computer for the first time in a while. When I try to turn on the chrome remote desktop to share my device, I get "An unknown error has occurred." when I decide the PIN. I tried reinstalling it, and at the final step I'm told to type the command "/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop --start". However, when I do that, I get the following:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.policykit.exec ===
Authentication is needed to run `/usr/bin/systemctl' as the super user
Authenticating as: choilinux,,, (choilinux)
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized
```

This didn't appear the first time I installed google remote desktop. I tried my password for sudo, but that doesn't work for this, and I'm not sure what how to get through this. I'm unsure if the "An unknown error has occurred" is because of this, but it's the only problem I can think of.